# Unregistering broadcast receivers on onDestroy() and onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a flow in my android app where it is possible to open a chain of user profile activities, one activity from another.

Example : User profile A is opened where it contains a list of other user profiles. clicking an item from this list will open user profile B. Again, it lists other user profiles **where user profile A might be part of**. So clicking this item will open another activity of user profile A.
The app user can perform an action on the current activity of user profile A which needs to be reflected on all other user profile A activities in the back stack. So what i did was registered a receiver in the user profile activity that checks for the activity user id against the one coming from the broadcast and perform the relevant actions on the UI.

The problem is, that i cannot unreigster the receiver on onPause() or onStop() (according to a lot of threads recommendations here) since this is kindda counterproductive to what im trying to build here. And according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) onDestroy() is not guarunteed to be called every time the activity terminates.

So what im basically asking here is - Is it a good practice to register all activity receivers on onCreate() and unregister them **both on onDestroy() and onSaveInstanceState()** so i will be 100% sure they are cleaned up on activity destruction ?

The only mention i saw in the documentation that recomments not to unregister receivers in onSaveInstanceState() was here - [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) - and it only says

> Do not unregister in Activity.onSaveInstanceState(), because this won't be called if the user moves back in the history stack

EDIT:
Ok, i just saw this quote in the [onDestroy() spec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) :

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (**or any others**) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

So onSaveInstanceState() will not be called also.
But arent receivers qualified as things that are NOT "intended to remain around after the process goes away" ? I dont get why onDestroy() is not called in such situations. What happens to other resources that are released there (not just receivers) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, using broadcast receiver to detect which Activity instance is running is not a good idea. You should use single instance for every Activity. Another solution is that you can create view stack in one Activity instead of Activity stack. Switching view is easier than switching Activity. As to how to use onDestroy and onSaveInstanceState(), it depends on your scenario. If you finish your Activity, the onDestroy will be called. If your Activity is destroyed by system in some situation, like screen rotation, the onSaveInstanceState will be triggered.

Comment: Will onSaveInstanceState be called also when the system terminates an activity to free up memory ?

Comment: Probably not, whereas onLowMemory() may be triggered